# thrust::unique on float3 tuple

Tags: cuda, unique, thrust

I'm trying to use `thrust::unique` over `float3` tuples. However, it seems that it is not returning correct results. Here is a full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/unique.h>

// --- Equality between two float3's
__host__ __device__ __forceinline__ bool operator==(const float3 &a, const float3 &b) { 
    return ((a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y) && (a.z == b.z)); }

// --- Binary predicate for a tuple pair
typedef thrust::tuple<float3, float3> tuple_t;
struct tupleEqual
{
    __host__ __device__
        bool operator()(tuple_t x, tuple_t y)
    {
        return ((x.get<0>() == y.get<0>()) && (x.get<1>() == y.get<1>()));
    }
};

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main(void)
{
    const int N = 6;

    thrust::device_vector<float3> v(N), d(N);
    thrust::device_vector<tuple_t> vd(N);

    v[0] = make_float3(2.f, 5.f, 9.f);      d[0] = make_float3(2.f, 3.f, 10.f);
    v[1] = make_float3(3.f, 2.f, 1.f);      d[1] = make_float3(2.f, 5.f, 9.f);
    v[2] = make_float3(2.f, 5.f, 9.f);      d[2] = make_float3(2.f, 3.f, 10.f);
    v[3] = make_float3(2.f, 3.f, 10.f);     d[3] = make_float3(2.f, 5.f, 9.f);
    v[4] = make_float3(2.f, 3.f, 10.f);     d[4] = make_float3(1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
    v[5] = make_float3(2.f, 5.f, 9.f);      d[5] = make_float3(2.f, 3.f, 10.f);

    vd[0] = thrust::make_tuple(v[0], d[0]);
    vd[1] = thrust::make_tuple(v[1], d[1]);
    vd[2] = thrust::make_tuple(v[2], d[2]);
    vd[3] = thrust::make_tuple(v[3], d[3]);
    vd[4] = thrust::make_tuple(v[4], d[4]);
    vd[5] = thrust::make_tuple(v[5], d[5]);

    auto new_end = thrust::unique(vd.begin(), vd.end(), tupleEqual());

    const size_t Nnew = new_end - vd.begin();

    printf("Nnew = %d\n", Nnew);
    for (int k = 0; k < Nnew; k++) {
        tuple_t temp = vd[k];
        float3 vtemp = thrust::get<0>(temp);
        float3 dtemp = thrust::get<1>(temp);
        printf("%d %f %f %f %f %f %f\n", k, vtemp.x, vtemp.y, vtemp.z, dtemp.x, dtemp.y, dtemp.z);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result I'm obtaining is

```
Nnew = 6
0 2.000000 5.000000 9.000000 2.000000 3.000000 10.000000
1 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 2.000000 5.000000 9.000000
2 2.000000 5.000000 9.000000 2.000000 3.000000 10.000000
3 2.000000 3.000000 10.000000 2.000000 5.000000 9.000000
4 2.000000 3.000000 10.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
5 2.000000 5.000000 9.000000 2.000000 3.000000 10.000000
```

which is exactly the input without any duplicate removal.

I'm compiling with Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015, using either CUDA 8.0 or CUDA 9.1 (the result is the same).

My question is: *what I'm doing wrong?*

Comment: I don't understand your question. There are no duplicates in the input data that I can see..... If I add a duplicate, it is successfully removed

Comment: `thrust::unique` doesn't remove duplicates no matter how they are presented.  They must be grouped together, first.  Read the functional description [here](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#gae5a90c7aa7c2370087c142936d405e8c).  To wit: "For each group of **consecutive elements** in the range [first, last) with the same value"   You have no such sequences in your input.

Comment: According to the documentation, [`thrust::unique`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#gacc951d5d2780083d91639e6d98b8cd4b) removes duplicate elements only if they occur consecutively in the input sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you don't see any change in the output is that your inputs do no contain any *duplicate sequences*. If I modify the input in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/unique.h>

__host__ __device__ __forceinline__ bool operator==(const float3 &a, const float3 &b) { 
    return ((a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y) && (a.z == b.z)); }

typedef thrust::tuple<float3, float3> tuple_t;
struct tupleEqual
{
    __host__ __device__
        bool operator()(tuple_t x, tuple_t y)
    {
        return ((x.get<0>() == y.get<0>()) && (x.get<1>() == y.get<1>()));
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    const int N = 6;

    thrust::device_vector<float3> v(N), d(N);
    thrust::device_vector<tuple_t> vd(N);

    v[0] = make_float3(2.f, 5.f, 9.f);      d[0] = make_float3(2.f, 3.f, 10.f);
    v[1] = make_float3(2.f, 5.f, 9.f);      d[1] = make_float3(2.f, 3.f, 10.f);
    v[2] = make_float3(2.f, 3.f, 10.f);     d[2] = make_float3(2.f, 5.f, 9.f);
    v[3] = make_float3(2.f, 3.f, 10.f);     d[3] = make_float3(2.f, 5.f, 9.f);
    v[4] = make_float3(2.f, 3.f, 10.f);     d[4] = make_float3(2.f, 5.f, 9.f);
    v[5] = make_float3(2.f, 3.f, 10.f);     d[5] = make_float3(2.f, 5.f, 9.f);

    vd[0] = thrust::make_tuple(v[0], d[0]);
    vd[1] = thrust::make_tuple(v[1], d[1]);
    vd[2] = thrust::make_tuple(v[2], d[2]);
    vd[3] = thrust::make_tuple(v[3], d[3]);
    vd[4] = thrust::make_tuple(v[4], d[4]);
    vd[5] = thrust::make_tuple(v[5], d[5]);

    auto new_end = thrust::unique(vd.begin(), vd.end(), tupleEqual());
    const size_t Nnew = new_end - vd.begin();

    printf("Nnew = %zu\n", Nnew);
    for (int k = 0; k < Nnew; k++) {
        tuple_t temp = vd[k];
        float3 vtemp = thrust::get<0>(temp);
        float3 dtemp = thrust::get<1>(temp);
        printf("%d %f %f %f %f %f %f\n", k, vtemp.x, vtemp.y, vtemp.z, dtemp.x, dtemp.y, dtemp.z);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

so that it contains sequences of identical inputs, then the removal works as expected:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -std=c++11 -o float3 float3.cu
$ ./float3
Nnew = 2
0 2.000000 5.000000 9.000000 2.000000 3.000000 10.000000
1 2.000000 3.000000 10.000000 2.000000 5.000000 9.000000
```

[thrust::unique](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#gacc951d5d2780083d91639e6d98b8cd4b) only removes repetitions of identical sequences in the input iterators. It does not sort. Quoting from the documentation:

> For each group of *consecutive* elements in the range [first, last)
>   with the same value, unique removes all but the first element of the
>   group.

Emphasis mine. Your only error here is one of understanding of the operation the function performs. The code you have written is correct and works as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for having pointed me out that duplicate elements must be _consecutive_. To expiate my lack of attention, I have provided a modification of my code introducing a double ordering using 3D Morton codes.

Answer (score 2):

Talonmies have already answered my question, pointing me out that the duplicate elements must be **consecutive**, which I was missing yesterday.

I'm providing below a modification of my code by introducing a double ordering, using a [3D Morton code](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/thinking-parallel-part-iii-tree-construction-gpu/), with respect to `v` and `d`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/unique.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>

/*********************************/
/* EQUALITY BETWEEN TWO FLOAT3'S */
/*********************************/
__host__ __device__ __forceinline__ bool operator==(const float3 &a, const float3 &b) {
    return ((a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y) && (a.z == b.z)); }

/*************************************/
/* BINARY PREDICATE FOR A TUPLE PAIR */
/*************************************/
typedef thrust::tuple<float3, float3> tuple_t;
struct tupleEqual
{
    __host__ __device__
        bool operator()(tuple_t x, tuple_t y)
    {
        return ((x.get<0>() == y.get<0>()) && (x.get<1>() == y.get<1>()));
    }
};

/**********************************/
/* MORTON ENCODER KERNEL FUNCTION */
/**********************************/
// --- Expands a 10-bit integer into 30 bits by inserting 2 zeros after each bit.
__host__ __device__ __forceinline__ unsigned int expandBits(unsigned int v)
{
    v = (v * 0x00010001u) & 0xFF0000FFu;
    v = (v * 0x00000101u) & 0x0F00F00Fu;
    v = (v * 0x00000011u) & 0xC30C30C3u;
    v = (v * 0x00000005u) & 0x49249249u;
    return v;
}

// --- Calculates a 30-bit Morton code for the given 3D point located within the unit cube [0,1].
__host__ __device__ __forceinline__ unsigned int morton3D(float x, float y, float z)
{
    x = min(max(x * 1024.0f, 0.0f), 1023.0f);
    y = min(max(y * 1024.0f, 0.0f), 1023.0f);
    z = min(max(z * 1024.0f, 0.0f), 1023.0f);
    unsigned int xx = expandBits((unsigned int)x);
    unsigned int yy = expandBits((unsigned int)y);
    unsigned int zz = expandBits((unsigned int)z);
    return xx * 4 + yy * 2 + zz;
}

/*************************/
/* CUSTOMIZED COMPARATOR */
/*************************/
struct customizedComparator {
    __host__ __device__
        bool operator()(const tuple_t &t1, const tuple_t &t2) {

        float3 v1 = t1.get<0>();
        float3 d1 = t1.get<1>();

        float3 v2 = t2.get<0>();
        float3 d2 = t2.get<1>();

        unsigned int m1 = morton3D(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
        unsigned int n1 = morton3D(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);

        unsigned int p1 = morton3D(d1.x, d1.y, d1.z);
        unsigned int q1 = morton3D(d2.x, d2.y, d2.z);

        if (m1 != n1) return (m1 < n1);
        else return (p1 < q1);

    }
};

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main(void)
{
    const int N = 6;

    thrust::device_vector<float3> v(N), d(N);

    v[0] = make_float3(.2f, .5f, .09f);     d[0] = make_float3(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.1f);
    v[1] = make_float3(.3f, .2f, .1f);      d[1] = make_float3(.2f, .5f, .09f);
    v[2] = make_float3(.2f, .5f, .09f);     d[2] = make_float3(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.1f);
    v[3] = make_float3(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.1f);   d[3] = make_float3(.2f, .5f, .09f);
    v[4] = make_float3(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.1f);   d[4] = make_float3(.1f, .1f, .1f);
    v[5] = make_float3(.2f, .5f, .09f);     d[5] = make_float3(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.1f);

    thrust::sort(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(v.begin(), d.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(v.begin(), d.begin())) + N, customizedComparator());

    auto new_end = thrust::unique(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(v.begin(), d.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(v.begin(), d.begin())) + N, tupleEqual());

    const size_t Nnew = new_end - thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(v.begin(), d.begin()));

    printf("Nnew = %d\n", Nnew);
    for (int k = 0; k < Nnew; k++) {
        float3 vtemp = v[k];
        float3 dtemp = d[k];
        printf("%d %f %f %f %f %f %f\n", k, vtemp.x, vtemp.y, vtemp.z, dtemp.x, dtemp.y, dtemp.z);
    }

    return 0;
}
```